# How to get notification for audio streaming status from AVPlayer?

Tags: iphone, audio, streaming, avplayer

I am using AVPlayer to stream some live HTTP audio, not AVAudioPlayer which does not support live HTTP audio streaming, the question is, how do I get the status of current playback? For example:

Tap Play Button -> [Loading] -> [Playing]
Tap Pause Button -> [Paused]

I need to show a spinner when loading, show a pause button when playing and show a play button when paused, I know I can observe the 'status' and 'rate' properties of AVPlayer:

rate:
the current rate of playback. 0.0 means “stopped”, 1.0 means “play at the natural rate of the current item”.

status:
Indicates whether the player can be used for playback.

```
AVPlayerStatusUnknown,
AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay,
AVPlayerStatusFailed
```

so there is no way to indicate the audio is "LOADING", and after the status changes to AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay, it still takes some time to have the audio playing(maybe because it is a live audio).

But anyway, how do I get the correct status of current playback? I know there is an AudioStream from Matt, but it does not support HTTP Live audio.

Thanks very much!

Comment: I might be missing something in your question but the time between calling [avPlayer start] and the rate going to 1.0 is the "loading" period. Set your own internal state to 'loading' as soon as you call [start] and then set it to 'playing' as soon as the rate goes to 1.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used

```
    [self.mPlayerItem addObserver:self 
                   forKeyPath:kStatusKey 
                      options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionInitial | NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                      context:AVPlayerDemoPlaybackViewControllerStatusObservationContext];
```

to monitor the status key ("status"). Then I created the player

```
[self setPlayer:[AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:self.mPlayerItem]];
```

And in the observeValueForKeyPath

```
    if (context == AVPlayerDemoPlaybackViewControllerStatusObservationContext)
{        
    AVPlayerStatus status = [[change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] integerValue];
    switch (status)
    {
            /* Indicates that the status of the player is not yet known because 
             it has not tried to load new media resources for playback */
        case AVPlayerStatusUnknown:
        {
            [lblvalidation setText:@"Loading..."];

            NSLog(@"AVPlayerStatusUnknown");
        }
            break;

        case AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay:
        {
            /* Once the AVPlayerItem becomes ready to play, i.e. 
             [playerItem status] == AVPlayerItemStatusReadyToPlay,
             its duration can be fetched from the item. */

            NSLog(@"AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay");

            [self.player play];
            [lblvalidation setText:@"Playing..."];
        }
            break;

        case AVPlayerStatusFailed:
        {
            [lblvalidation setText:@"Error..."];
            NSLog(@"AVPlayerStatusFailed");
        }
            break;
    }
}
```

this works for me... I hope it help for you.

Comment: Will it work the following scenario? Player is playing when the network is slow or down will it return AVPlayerStatusUnknown?

Answer (score 1):

Updated for Swift 2:

```
 private var AVPlayerDemoPlaybackViewControllerStatusObservationContext = 0
```

Add observer:

```
player.currentItem!.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "status", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, context: &AVPlayerDemoPlaybackViewControllerStatusObservationContext)
```

Observer

```
override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {

    if context == &AVPlayerDemoPlaybackViewControllerStatusObservationContext {
        if let change = change as? [String: Int]
        {
            let status = change[NSKeyValueChangeNewKey]!

            switch status {
            case AVPlayerStatus.Unknown.rawValue:
                print("The status of the player is not yet known because it has not tried to load new media resources for playback")

            case AVPlayerStatus.ReadyToPlay.rawValue:
                self.playButtonPressed(playButton)
                print("The player is Ready to Play")

            case AVPlayerStatus.Failed.rawValue:
                print("The player failed to load the video")

            default:
                print("Other status")
            }
        }
    } else {
        super.observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath, ofObject: object, change: change, context: context)
    }

}
```